# Position absolute is not working with overflow auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list where I'm using position that is working only inside the div, it should be working outside also. When I remove overflow auto it's working fine. How to fix this issue?

```css
.customize-table {
  background: #ccc;
}

.customize-table .thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.customize-table .row {
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.trade-box-3-1 .customize-table .tbody .row:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.customize-table-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -25px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.4em 1em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
}

.customize-table .tbody {
  height: 285px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container p-5">
    <div class="customize-table">
      <div class="thead">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 text-light-purple text-left">Pair <img src="images/icon-down.svg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="col-md text-light-purple text-left">Price</div>
          <div class="col-md text-light-purple text-right">Change</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tbody">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="customize-table-tooltip">tooltip</div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="customize-table-tooltip">tooltip</div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you say removing `overflow auto` and it works fine, but `overflow auto` cant be removed then i assume?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Since you are using bootstrap, is there any reason not to use the bootstrap tooltips ? Your problem is, that you attach your tooltips inside of your table but hide everything outside of it's boundaries. Bootstrap tooltips are attachable to other containers - like the body itself - therefore solving that issue.

Comment: to keep your tooltip inside the scrolling container area , you may add : `
  padding-left:28px;` to thead and tbody to keep both aligned.  a gradient can be used to draw the color background, so it starts at 25/28px from the left .

Answer (score 0):

demo made from my earlier comment ***(this is an average trick , it doesn't make absolute element to show outside a scrolling container).***

> to keep your tooltip inside the scrolling container area , you may add : 
>     `padding-left:28px;` to thead and tbody to keep both aligned.  a gradient can be used to draw the color background, so it starts at 25/28px from the left .

```css
.customize-table {
  background: linear-gradient(to right,transparent 28px, #ccc 28px);
  margin-left:-28px;
}

.customize-table .thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding-left:28px;
}

.customize-table .row {
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.trade-box-3-1 .customize-table .tbody .row:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.customize-table-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -25px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.4em 1em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
}

.customize-table .tbody {
  height: 285px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left:28px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container p-5">
    <div class="customize-table">
      <div class="thead">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 text-light-purple text-left">Pair <img src="images/icon-down.svg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="col-md text-light-purple text-left">Price</div>
          <div class="col-md text-light-purple text-right">Change</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tbody">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="customize-table-tooltip">tooltip</div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="customize-table-tooltip">tooltip</div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-white text-left"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>ETH/USDT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-white text-left">0.00000848</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <div class="text-red text-right">-4.01%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```